# Cómo establecer variables con nombres dinámicos desde array?

Tags: javascript, array, variables

Pido su apoyo para logra generar la asignación de valores a una variable en JavaScript; el detalle es que el nombre del la variable viene desde un Array:

```
var idInputs01 = ["D01", "D02", "Gr", "PAtm", "Tb", "Tf", "CpCv", "Rp", "Rh", "Le", "Ld", "Pf1", "Pd"];

    var contador = 0;
    idInputs01.forEach(function (X) {
      alert("X= " + X + "\ninput" + contador + "= " + parseFloat(document.getElementById("input" + contador).value));
      window[X]= parseFloat(document.getElementById("input" + contador).value);
            contador = ++contador;
    });
```

La idea es que (por ejemplo) se genere la variable "D01" (que és lo importante de mi consulta) y se le asigne el valor de input.

la instrucción "alert" si me presenta los valores correctos de nombre de variable y valor: 
X=D01 
input0= 8.171

... pero cuando mas adelante consulto el valor de la variable "D01" el resultado es "undefined"; es decir el window[X] no funciona (como yo esperaba).

Algún consejo?

Gracias de antemano al foro.

Saludos desde México.

---

Gracias por su interes.
(Complemento)

El contexto del problema es el siguiente:

Tengo 15 inputs con su respectivo valor introducido por el usuario en la pagina HTML.
Estos 15 valores seran usados en una subrutina para realizar calculos, ya hice la siguiente forma de programacion:

```
var D01 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input0").value)
var D02 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input1").value)
var Gr = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input2").value)
var PAtm = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input3").value)
var Tb = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input4").value)
var Tf = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input5").value)
var CpCv = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input6").value)
var Exp1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input7").value)
var Exp2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input8").value)
var Rp = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input9").value)
var Rh = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input10").value)
var Le = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input11").value)
var Ld = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input12").value)
var Pf1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input13").value)
var Pd = parseFloat(document.getElementById("input14").value)
```

Como ven es un código repetitivo.

Por esto quiero sustituir este codigo con lo que presenté arriba:

```
    var idInputs01 = ["D01", "D02", "Gr", "PAtm", "Tb", "Tf", "CpCv", "Rp", "Rh", "Le", "Ld", "Pf1", "Pd"];


var contador = 0;
idInputs01.forEach(function (X) {
  alert("X= " + X + "\ninput" + contador + "= " + parseFloat(document.getElementById("input" + contador).value));
  window[X]= parseFloat(document.getElementById("input" + contador).value);
        contador = ++contador;
});
```

Tengo 3 memorias de calculo mas con diferente numero de datos y estoy programando de tal forma que pueda cubrir esa numero variable de datos.

Espero haber explicado mejor el problema a resolver.

Gracias.

Comment: `pero cuando mas adelante consulto el valor de la variable "D01"` = ¿en dónde haces esto?, [edit] la pregunta con mas detalles; la verdad no entiendo porqué quieres crear variables dinámicas par asignarles el valor a un input = podrías pasarle el valor directamente al input *(o no entendí bien tu problema)*...

Comment: La varibale "D01" la utilizo en una formula; sin embargo con una llamada de:<br/> > alert ("D01= " + D01)  <br/>  el vaor devuelto es "undefined".

Comment: Que tal @Mauricio Arias Olave.    La varibale "D01" la utilizo en una formula; sin embargo con una llamada de:  alert ("D01= " + D01);  el valor devuelto es "undefined".   (perdon, pero aun no manejo bien el sistema de etiquetas en estos comentarios de respuesta).

Comment: también depende en dónde estás usando `window[X]`, me imagino que `var D01` es una variable local *(o dentro de una función)*.

Comment: Es correcto @Mauricio, pero los cálculos se hacen en la misma función y el resultado es hacia un input del HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas son Maps.

```
var miObjeto = {
    'variable': 'valor',
    'otraVariable': 'Otro Valor'
};
```

Si quieres agregar una nueva variable es tan facil como

```
miObjeto['nuevaVariable']='nuevo valor'
```

Answer (score 0):

creo que de esta forma es mas fácil recorrer tu array para poder manejar los indices y los valores...

```
var idInputs01 = ["D01", "D02", "Gr", "PAtm", "Tb", "Tf", "CpCv", "Rp", "Rh", "Le", "Ld", "Pf1", "Pd"];
var contador = 0;

$.each(idInputs01, function(index, value){
//alert("Indice:"+index+"Valor:"+value+"Contador:"+contador);
contador++;
});
```

comentame si es asi para poder ayudarte con el resto...